# How to have Drush make automatically find libraries download path?

Tags: drush

I don't know from what URL's I got my libraries files from. Is there a way for Drush Make to find those URL's, a command?

Additionally, what URL/Path can I use for my own custom modules?
Can I use a local path in a URL so the libraries are sourced locally?

Comment: How would you imagine that? You can use search engines to look for library, but drush is just a mindless script. It either have path provided or it does not, simple as that. It can't search the web, evaluate results, ask on forums where something was moved or if there is any archive. It simply can't. So what is the mechanism you are thinking of?

Comment: What if I save the libraries on my PC. For example they are now in:  cd x:\xampp-portable\htdocs\xxx\sites\all\libraries   what URL could I put into  libraries[audiojs][download][url] = ""   Like this?:    libraries[audiojs][download][url] = "x:\xampp-portable\htdocs\xxx\sites\all\libraries"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Molot states, there's no way for drush to know about any arbitrary library; you need to know the source URL to give it.

For any custom module project, you can use `git` or `file` download `type` to retrieve it from a git repo or an HTTP source.

```
projects[example][type] = "module"
projects[example][subdir] = "custom"
projects[example][download][type] = "git"
projects[example][download][url] = "git://github.com/jane_doe/example.git"
projects[example][branch] = "dev"

projects[example][type] = "module"
projects[example][download][type] = "file"
projects[example][download][url] = "http://example.com/example.tgz"
projects[example][subdir] = "custom"
```

The same for libraries

```
libraries[ckeditor][download][type]= "get"
libraries[ckeditor][download][url] = "http://download.cksource.com/CKEditor/CKEditor/CKEditor%203.4/ckeditor_3.4.zip"
libraries[ckeditor][directory_name] = "ckeditor"
libraries[ckeditor][destination] = "libraries"
```

Lastly, for local files you can use the `file://` protocol in the `url` property to source the file from the local machine. See the [Drush makefile docs](http://www.drush.org/en/master/make/) for more information.

Comment: I'm having an issue using 'drush make' command. The command downloads the library correctly (under libraries folder), but it doesn't unzip it. Does libraries[module][download][url] suppose to unzip the file?